# Javascript is automatically clicking in the EventSystem? What did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

The code is supposed to redirect the user to another internal page. However when the page loads with the code in it it automatically redirects the user without the user having to click the button.

I'm pretty new. I don't know what to try. I think it should work as is.

```
document.querySelector(".choice").addEventListener('apple', Redirect());

function Redirect()
{
    window.location = "challenge.html";
}
```

The expected result is that the user would click the text that contain the choice class and it would redirect the user to the challenge page.

The actual result is when the page loads it automatically redirects the user to the challenge page without the user having to click the button.

Comment: Where it says 'apple' i put 'click' i was just trying to see what would happen if i changed the click to something else.

Comment: Replace `Redirect()` with `Redirect`

Comment: cont above.. overwise your executing the function immediatly instead of when clicked..

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the event handler in this line:

`document.querySelector(".choice").addEventListener('apple', Redirect());`

Remove the parentheses:

`document.querySelector(".choice").addEventListener('apple', Redirect);`

You need to pass a reference to `addEventListener` otherwise with your current setup not only will the user be redirected immediately after the listener is registered, the button will also do nothing because the `Redirect` function is not returning something

Comment: THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH! I LOVE YOU